# Can you use a custom trained model for feature extraction?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, resnet

I am trying to develop an algorithm using features extracted from images to find similar items.

I have this code I am working with:

```
def get_pil_image_from_path(path):
    try:
        image = Image.open(path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return image

def get_color_image(img):
    img = img.resize((224, 224))
    img = img.convert('RGB')
    return img

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

class VGFeatureExtractor:
    def __init__(self):
        # Use VGG-16 as the architecture and ImageNet for the weight
        base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')
        # Customize the model to return features from fully-connected layer
        self.model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('fc1').output)

def extract(self, img):
    img = get_color_image(img)

    # Reformat the image
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)

    # Extract features
    feature = self.model.predict(x)[0]

    # Change shape to (1, 4096) as the model expects
    feature = feature.reshape(1, feature.shape[0])
    return feature / np.linalg.norm(feature)

image = get_pil_image_from_path(imagePath)
ve = VGFeatureExtractor()
features_vector = ve.extract(image)
```

Could I use my own [ResNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_neural_network) classification model I trained instead of the pretrained [ImageNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageNet) model, and would that show improvement?

Currently, the similar items suggested are not the same color. What can I do to improve this code?

I am using [Faiss](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki) to search the features and currently it is not doing well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
class SaveFeatures():
    features = None

   def __init__(self, m):
       self.hook = m.register_forward_hook(self.hook_fn)
       self.features = None

   def hook_fn(self, module, input, output):
       out = output.detach().cpu().numpy()
       if isinstance(self.features, type(None)):
           self.features = out
       else:
           self.features = np.row_stack((self.features, out))

   def remove(self):
       self.hook.remove()


class CustomFeatureExtractor:
    def __init__(self, learner):
        self.model = learner.model[1][4]  # Assumes the feature layer is at index 4
        self.learner = learner
    def extract(self, img):
        img = get_color_image(img)
        save_features = SaveFeatures(self.model)
        self.learner.predict(img)
        feature = save_features.features
        save_features.remove()
        return feature / np.linalg.norm(feature)
```

Here is the function I found after some research. I loaded my model using fast ai load_learner and passed it to CustomFeature extractor during intialization.